# What is the best approach to predict/ forecast the sales of 100s of parts?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, multilevel-analysis

I have been working on a sales database, aggregated and organized month wise, which has the sales trend of 600+ parts, of which 150 are major contributors. The parts can be aggregated into a part family meaning, for example, if we take a dataset of components which form part of automotive engines, we can group them into categories such camshafts, crankshafts, valve bodies, pistons, spark plugs and so on, each having different model based on engine size and type and requirement.

I have the following questions regarding how to proceed with data modelling, which are as follows:
1.Is it recommended to run 600+ Individual regression/forecast models for all the parts and then sum up for the category? In this case, how do I aggregate the train database into part categories and code them as hts or hierarchical time series?
2.Is it possible to build neural network modelling with hierarchical time series?

Comment: Look into [hierarchical forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=hierarchical+forecasting+answers%3A1).

Comment: I have had a look at Robert Hyndman's text on hierarchical forecasting. The idea is to not lose originality in individual forecasts- I would like to adopt bottom up approach but need to decide how to aggregate demand into an aggregate and after that, how to build/code data models or aggregated data sets. I am looking to adopt NN/RNN for this problem and I need to look at how I can bring this in with Hierarchical time series